# Would an iPhone charging cable electrocution cause lasting damage?

Tags: charging

Some time ago I accidentally touched the tip of a 2-meter long iPhone charging cable while the charging adapter was plugged in. It gave me a slight jump but nothing more than that. I was indoors and barefoot, and my hands were dry(I think).

I live in an area where the normal voltage for any outlet is 220V. Am I supposed to be okay?

Comment: you need to ask your doctor these kinds of questions as he knows your medical history. *GENERALLY* a 5V circuit will not harm you, but it all depends on your medical condition and history.

Comment: If you're getting 220VAC on your iPhone charging cable, you should have an electrician check your outlets AND take your charging adapter and cable to an Apple store. But of course do this AFTER you've done as @SteveChambers suggested, and seen a doctor.